# How do I connect website running on Windows Server 2019 via IIS in AWS to a RDS database?

Tags: amazon-web-services, iis, database-connection, connection-string, windows-server-2019

I am using Windows Server 2019 on AWS (using a EC2 instance) and want to connect my website to the RDS database I set up. I'm using IIS in WS2019 to modify the connection string to try and connect to my database but having trouble.

I can use SSMS to confirm that my database is accessible but when my app runs I get a database connection error.

I've tried modifying the connection strings in IIS. Currently it is SQLConnection='data source=tsidev.cl5cfu2wi9bq.ca-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com,1433;initial catalog=tsi;integrated security=True;User ID=XXXX;Password=XXXX' but doesn't connect.

What should my connection string be? (I left out the login/password info that follows the port 1433 in the connection string above).

The error I receive is:
'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.'

Comment: What connection error are you getting?

Comment: I get a 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.

Comment: Try changing integrated security=False

Comment: Thanks for the response Rich. I tried that, but get the same error.

Comment: SOLVED:
The connection strings application in the IIS on WS2019 was overwriting the web.config file for the website. The web.config contained a variable 'providerName' which was not entered in IIS.
Thanks to all that looked/responded and hopefully this will help someone else in the future.